# Populating listView items

Tags: c#, listview

How to add an item on the third column? I have a code but it only adds an item upto the second column.

```
lstProjectFiles.Items.Add(f3.FullName).SubItems.Add(f4.FullName);
```

Comment: How can we understand which listview do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
 ListViewItem lvi = lstProjectFiles.Items.Add(f3.FullName);
 lvi.SubItems.Add(f4.FullName);
 lvi.SubItems.Add("your 3rd column");
```